# Generate this contour plot

Tags: plotting, integral-transforms

I have the following complex function:

```
Fnew[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_] := (4 Sqrt[a/b] b E^(-(((c + d)^2 + (2 I a + b (c + d - 2 e) + 2 I f)^2/b^2)/(4 g^2))) Sqrt[a/(b g^2)] (π Erf[(2 a - I b (c + d - 2 e) + 2 f)/(2 b g)] + I (Log[-(b/(2 I a + b (c + d - 2 e) + 2 I f))] - 
  Log[b/(2 I a + b (c + d - 2 e) + 2 I f)])))/((2 a - I b (c + d - 2 e) + 2 f) Sqrt[π])
```

where all of the quantities `a,c,d,e,f,g` are real. I want the following contour plot

```
ContourPlot[Integrate[Abs[Fnew[1, 1, c, d, e, 0, g]]^2, {c, -∞, ∞}, {d, -∞, ∞}], {e, 0, 20}, {g, 0, 50}]
```

However the difficulty is in finding the integral of `Abs[Fnew[1, 1, c, d, e, 0, g]]^2` first. Mathematica returns the same input.

Any suggestions on how to calculate this integral or generate the contour plot?

Comment: `ContourPlot` only handles 2 dimensional functions!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, indeed! I am trying to plot the function over the variables `e` and `g`.

Comment: Sorry! Perhaps you can take a step further bei substituting the integrand `Abs[...]^2` by `ComplexExpand[# Conjugate[#] &[Fnew[1, 1, c, d, e, 0, g]]] // Simplify`

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be the numerical integration:

```
integrand[c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, e_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] = 
ComplexExpand[# Conjugate[#] &[Fnew[1, 1, c, d, e, 0,g]]] // Simplify

f[e_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[integrand[c, d, e,g], {c, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {d, -\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

For example

```
f[1, 1] 
(*72.8287*)
```

But evaluation is very slow, though `ContourPlot[f[e,g],...]` might run a long time.

Comment: Using `ComplexExpand[# Conjugate[#]` instead of `Abs[]^2` is in fact exactly what I had before. Using `Conjugate` usually is a little tricky since it conjugates all parameters rather than just changing `I` for `-I`. Also, how long would it take to generate a contour plot using `f[e,g]`?

Comment: Setting `, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3` inside NIntegrate  the calculation of one point lasts ~5seconds. ContourPlot might take >500seconds...

Comment: ok, i guess I'll have to do a `ListContourPlot`. What should be a good step size for this?